# How to perform queries in Django following double-join relationships (or: How to get around Django's restrictions on ManyToMany "through" models?)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

There must be a way to do this query through the ORM, but I'm not seeing it.

### The Setup

Here's what I'm modelling: one Tenant can occupy multiple rooms and one User can own multiple rooms. So Rooms have an FK to Tenant and an FK to User. Rooms are also maintained by a (possibly distinct) User.

That is, I have these (simplified) models:

```
class Tenant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Room(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    maintainer = models.ForeignKey(User)
    tenant = models.ForeignKey(Tenant)
```

### The Problem

Given a Tenant, I want the Users owning a room which they occupy.

The relevant SQL query would be:

```
SELECT auth_user.id, ...
FROM tenants_tenant, tenants_room, auth_user
WHERE tenants_tenant.id = tenants_room.tenant_id
AND tenants_room.owner_id = auth_user.id;
```

Getting any individual value off the related User objects can be done with, for example, `my_tenant.rooms.values_list('owner__email', flat=True)`, but getting a full queryset of Users is tripping me up.

Normally one way to solve it would be to set up a `ManyToMany` field on my `Tenant` model pointing at `User` with `TenantRoom` as the 'through' model. That won't work in this case, though, because the `TenantRoom` model has a second (unrelated) `ForeignKey` to `User`([see "restictions"](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)). Plus it seems like needless clutter on the Tenant model.

Doing `my_tenant.rooms.values_list('user', flat=True)` gets me close, but returns a ValuesListQuerySet of user IDs rather than a queryset of the actual User objects.

### The Question

So: is there a way to get a queryset of the actual model instances, through the ORM, using just one query?

---

**Edit**

If there is, in fact, no way to do this directly in one query through the ORM, what is the best (some combination of most performant, most idiomatic, most readable, etc.) way to accomplish what I'm looking for? Here are the options I see:

1. Subselect

   ```
   users = User.objects.filter(id__in=my_tenant.rooms.values_list('user'))
   ```
2. Subselect through Python (see [Performance considerations](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) for reasoning behind this)

   ```
   user_ids = id__in=my_tenant.rooms.values_list('user')
   users = User.objects.filter(id__in=list(user_ids))
   ```
3. Raw SQL:

   ```
   User.objects.all("""SELECT auth_user.*
   FROM tenants_tenant, tenants_room, auth_user
   WHERE tenants_tenant.id = tenants_room.tenant_id
   AND tenants_room.owner_id = auth_user.id""")
   ```
4. Others...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to do this is with `related_name`:

```
class Tenant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Room(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='owns')
    maintainer = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='maintains')
    tenant = models.ForeignKey(Tenant)
```

Then you can do this:

```
jrb = User.objects.create(username='jrb')
bill = User.objects.create(username='bill')
bob = models.Tenant.objects.create(name="Bob")
models.Room.objects.create(owner=jrb, maintainer=bill, tenant=bob)

User.objects.filter(owns__tenant=bob)
```

Comment: Wow. Brainfart. I do already have related_names on my models, but removed them as (what I thought to be) extraneous details in an attempt to minimize the example. I had my mind so set on figuring out how to follow the relationships forward that I somehow missed the all-to-obvious solution of going backwards from the User. Thanks for setting me straight!

Comment: @kRON I believe the `related_name` is required because of there being two FKs to User on the Room model. By default Django will add a `room_set` property to the User model, which works fine when a single FK is present, but becomes ambiguous when the second FK is added (I suspect what happens is the second FK just clobbers the first's assignment of `room_set`, but I haven't checked to confirm)

Comment: After hours of poring over the documentation, your answer has finally shown me what related names are about. Thank you so much, Jeff!